# collpase and expand all bootstrap 3 accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code which work till :
    when I click on collapse or expand All it works and changes the text of button from collapse all to expand all. Only problem is: when I open or close all the panels by clicking the header it should change the text of button as well.

I hope I have cleared enough my problem.

I haven't included Jquery and bootstrap external file in this example . but you can find example on following link.

[jsfiddle example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/26hu7o5y/)

**Jquery**

```
     $('.expand-all').click(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.toggleClass('collapse-all');
     if($this.hasClass('collapse-all')){
     $this.text(' Expand All');
     $('.panel-collapse.in')
     .collapse('hide');
     } 
     else {
     $this.text('Collapse All');
     $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
     .collapse('show');
     }
     });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-default openall">open all</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default closeall">close all</a>--><a href="#" class="btn btn-default expand-all">Collapse All</a>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="" >
                                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    ONe
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
                                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Two Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseThree">
                                        Collapsible Group Item #3
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Three Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem

```
$(".panel-heading a").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if($(".collapsed").length == $(".panel-heading").length){
            $(".btn-default").text(' Expand All');
          if(!$('.expand-all').hasClass('collapse-all')){
               $('.expand-all').addClass('collapse-all')
           }
        }else{
            $(".btn-default").text('Collapse All');
        }
    },100)    
})
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/26hu7o5y/4/

Comment: thank you or ur quick answer. but the problem is now. when its expanded I need to click twice to make it expand. even button shows expand all.

same I open all the panels manually (2times without clicking the button ) I need to click button twice.

Comment: here The fix http://jsfiddle.net/26hu7o5y/4/  check it out and let me know is this correct

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/sdevh4rh/)?

CODE:

```
$('.expand-all').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('collapse-all')){
        $this.text(' Expand All');
        $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        $this.removeClass('collapse-all');
    } else {
        $this.text('Collapse All');
        $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
        $this.addClass('collapse-all');
    }
});

$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function (obj) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $expand = $('.expand-all');
    if(obj.type=="show"){
        $expand.text('Collapse All').addClass('collapse-all');
    }
    else{
        if($('.collapse.in').not(obj.target).length == 0){
            $expand.text('Expand All').removeClass('collapse-all');
        }
    }
});
```

Also add `collapse-all` class to the button

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default expand-all collapse-all">Collapse All</a>
```